# Can I initialize var with null or some empty value? For after to define the variable as another type that I defined?

Tags: c#

```
private void SharingFieldOE2WellOE(InputData inputData)
{
    var resultsField = new Object();

    if (inputData.CashflowModel.Equals("BC"))
    {
       resultsField = new List<ResultsBC>();
    }
    else if (inputData.CashflowModel.Equals("GC"))
    {
       resultsField = new List<ResultsGC>();
    }

    resultsField[1].Date = "08/08/2017"
}
```

Above I cant to use index for resultsField because is Object type, not one List < Results?? > as I would like.
What I am doing wrong or how can I convert this object to my type defined?
Will exist only one Results?? type.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create an Interface that contains the common properties between `ResultsBC` and `ResultsGC`.  Then you just declare your variable as: `List<IResults> resultsField;`

Comment: No. `var` is determined by the compiler at design time.

Comment: `var` it doesn't dynamic type, it's only a syntax sugar for you, so when you use keyword `var` compiler knows the type of variable and you cannot change this type. So you can use a some common type: interface or base class to achive what you want or can use `dynamic` type for it

Comment: If you use this list anywhere else you'd have to declare it the same way everywhere; Do you use it anywhere outside the function or is it just in here?

Comment: It's also worth noting that initially assigning `new [Anything]` to `var results` is irrelevant; best case, it'll get optimized out since the assigned value is never used, and worst case, may (depending on how frequently the function is called) cause a performance hit.

Comment: Could you add some more details as to what happens in the function? We can't reason about everything from what you gave us

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign `null` to an object declared as `var`.

This might help (I haven't tested the code though!)

Create an interface for `ResultsBC` and `ResultsGC`- let's call it `IResults`.

```
private void SharingFieldOE2WellOE(InputData inputData)
{
    IEnumerable<IResults> resultsField = null;

    if (inputData.CashflowModel.Equals("BC"))
    {
       resultsField = new List<ResultsBC>();
    }
    else if (inputData.CashflowModel.Equals("GC"))
    {
       resultsField = new List<ResultsGC>();
    }

    // Convert IEnumerable to IList
    List<IResults> list = resultsField.ToList();
    list[1].Date = "08/08/2017"
}
```

Note the use of `IEnumerable` and the conversion of it to `IList` later. I think an `ICollection` will not allow this.

This is a good [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/) about `covariance` and `contravariance`

Comment: This is all sorts of wrong.  Why would you use a base class instead of an interface?  Why would you initialize the `resultsField` variable as anything just to wipe it away?  Why is `list` a `List<int>`?

Comment: @maccettura Code review feedback implemented and typos fixed! :-)

Comment: `You cannot assign null to an object declared as var.` You sure can.  `var n = (object)null;`  You can do the same for any nullable type.

Comment: Also `assign` isn't a good word here. You wouldn't be able to initialize with a bare `null`, but you would be able to assign it later

Comment: @JakubDąbek I showed right in my comment how you could initialize it with a null value. Even a null literal no less (although that one is far less common that initializing it with a variable that happens to have a `null` value).

Comment: I didn't say you can't initialize the variable with a null value, I meant a _bare_ null literal (without casts)